# Create PDF compile error "Application: defined or object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a VBA userform where the user searches the database sheet for certain terms. It generates the result in a separate sheet and when the user clicks the print button it creates a PDF that includes all the data in the search result sheet.

It is giving the compile error

> "Application: defined or object-defined error"

```
Sub CreatePDF()

    Sheet4.Select
    Range("A1:N25").Select
 

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SearchData").Select
        Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="D:\AliBinAli\Security Visitor App\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            Orientation:=xlLandscape, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
               
       
    Sheet4.Select
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

The highlighted line is:

```vb
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _ Type:=xlTypePDF, _             
  Filename:="D:\AliBinAli\Security Visitor App\temp.pdf", _             
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  Orientation:=xlLandscape, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: what line gets highlighted?

Comment: `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="D:\AliBinAli\Security Visitor App\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            Orientation:=xlLandscape, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Orientation

[`PageSetup.Orientation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.orientation)

[`Range.Orientation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.orientation)

There is no `Orientation` argument in the [`Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat).
You could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePDF()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SearchData")
        .PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="D:\AliBinAli\Security Visitor App\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With
    
    With Sheet4
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

or if you wanted to print the range:

```
Sub CreatePDF2()
 
    With Sheet4.Range("A1:N25")
        .Worksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="D:\AliBinAli\Security Visitor App\temp.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Worksheet.Activate
        .Cells(1).Select   
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked perfectly without a hitch.

Comment: @kamranmirza ,please mark as the answer so the thread shows as answered.